# Can someone tell me why my hour won't print the actual hour?

Tags: c, time, hour

I don't know what is wrong with my logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    time_t seconds=time(NULL);

    int time[5] = { 1,60,3600,86400,31536000 };
    int second = (seconds % time[1])/time[0];
    int minute = (seconds % time[2])/time[1];
    int hour = (seconds % time[3])/time[2];

    printf("%d:%d:%d\n", hour, minute, second);

}
```

It doesn't show an error, but I cannot print the accurate hour.

Comment: So what _does_ it show?

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but `time` is already an identifier for a function in the Standard Library. You´re using it with another meaning, causing UB.

Comment: What are you seeing, and what were you expecting? Note that the [hour will be in `UTC` by default](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Calendar-Time.html), so I would guess you are out by your timezone hours.

Comment: See http://current-timestamp.com/

Comment: @pmg Nice, but that site would be more useful if it also displayed local time.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of relying on those manual conversions, I would just use a `struct tm` instead and leave the conversions to the `localtime` function:

```
#include <time.h>
int main() {

    time_t now;
    struct tm *now_tm;
    int hour, minute, second;

    now = time(NULL);
    now_tm = localtime(&now);
    hour = now_tm->tm_hour;
    minute = now_tm->tm_min;
    second = now_tm->tm_sec;

    printf("%d:%d:%d\n", hour, minute, second);
}
```

This also takes care of the hour offset that you're observing, which I presume is due to a timezone difference.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is fine. It's just that you don't live near [Greenwich, London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time).

Comment: You don't need to live near Greenwich for that; You can live anywhere on the longitude of Greenwich (i.e., as far as you want north or south of Greenwich).

Comment: UK, Ireland, Iceland, Portugal, and a few countries in Western Africa: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/